# FFT to find autocorrelation function

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, correlation

I am trying to find the correlation function of the following stochastic process: [image] 
where beta and D are constants and xi(t) is a Gaussian noise term.

After simulating this process with the Euler method, I want to find the auto correlation function of this process. First of all, I have found an analytical solution for the correlation function and already used the definition of correlation function to simulate it and the two results were pretty close (please see the photo, the corresponding code is at the end of this post).

[image: figure 1, correlation function analytically and numerically]

(Figure 1)

---

Now I want to use the Wiener-Khinchin theorem (using fft) to find the correlation function by taking the fft of the realizations, multiply it with its conjugate and then find take the ifft to get the correlation function. But obviously I am getting results that are way off the expected correlation function, so I am pretty sure there is something I misunderstood in the code to get this wrong results..

Here is my code for the solution of the stochastic process (which I am sure it is right although my code might be sloppy) and my attempt to find the autocorrelaion with the fft:

```
N = 1000000
dt=0.01
gamma = 1
D=1
v_data = []
v_factor = math.sqrt(2*D*dt)
v=1
for t in range(N):
        F = random.gauss(0,1)
        v = v - gamma*dt + v_factor*F
        if v<0: ###boundary conditions.
            v=-v
        v_data.append(v)


def S(x,dt):  ### power spectrum 
    N=len(x)
    fft=np.fft.fft(x)
    s=fft*np.conjugate(fft)
 #   n=N*np.ones(N)-np.arange(0,N) #divide res(m) by (N-m)
    return s.real/(N)

c=np.fft.ifft(S(v_data,0.01))  ### correlation function 
t=np.linspace(0,1000,len(c))

plt.plot(t,c.real,label='fft method')
plt.xlim(0,20)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And this is what I would get using this method for the correlation function, 
[image]

And this is my code for the correlation function using the definition:

```
def c_theo(t,b,d): ##this was obtained by integrating the solution of the SDE 
    I1=((-t*d)+((d**2)/(b**2))-((1/4)*(b**2)*(t**2)))*special.erfc(b*t/(2*np.sqrt(d*t)))
    I2=(((d/b)*(np.sqrt(d*t/np.pi)))+((1/2)*(b*t)*(np.sqrt(d*t/np.pi))))*np.exp(-((b**2)*t)/(4*d))
    return I1+I2 

## this is the correlation function that was plotted in the figure 1 using the definition of the autocorrelation. 
Ntau = 500
sum2=np.zeros(Ntau)
c=np.zeros(Ntau)
v_mean=0

for i in range (0,N):
    v_mean=v_mean+v_data[i]
v_mean=v_mean/N
for itau in range (0,Ntau):
    for i in range (0,N-10*itau):
            sum2[itau]=sum2[itau]+v_data[i]*v_data[itau*10+i]
    sum2[itau]=sum2[itau]/(N-itau*10)    
    c[itau]=sum2[itau]-v_mean**2

t=np.arange(Ntau)*dt*10
plt.plot(t,c,label='numericaly')
plt.plot(t,c_theo(t,1,1),label='analyticaly')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

so would someone please point out where is the mistake in my code, and how could I simulate it better to get the right correlation function?

Comment: Can you post how you plot "analytically" and "numerically"?

Comment: @user2699 I just added them to the post.

Comment: The mean is to be substracted for the autocorrelation to decrease to zero. The zero frequency of the fft can equivalently be zeroed. Could you try `fft=np.fft.fft(x)` then `fft[0]=0` then `s=fft*np.conjugate(fft)` and return `s/N` ?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I corrected that, but I don't think that's so important since it's already real because of the multiplying with the conjugate

Comment: @francis thanks for the tip, actually it helped so the correlation function starts at the right point (the variance), but it's still decreasing too fast at the beginning...

Comment: I have a question if someone is still reading.. Why do we divide the power spectrum  by N (the number of sampling points) and not T (the total time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the code that I can see.

1. As [francis said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56009451/fft-to-find-autocorrelation-function?noredirect=1#comment98715027_56009451), you need to subtract the mean from your signal to get the autocorrelation to reach zero.
2. You plot your autocorrelation function with a wrong x-axis values.

   `v_data` is defined with:

   ```
    N = 1000000   % 1e6
    dt = 0.01     % 1e-2
   ```

   meaning that `t` goes from 0 to 1e4. However:

   ```
    t = np.linspace(0,1000,len(c))
   ```

   meaning that you plot with `t` from 0 to 1e3. You should probably define `t` with

   ```
    t = np.arange(N) * dt
   ```

   Looking at the plot, I'd say that stretching the blue line by a factor 10 would make it line up with the red line quite well.

Comment: thanks for the answer, actually that was the mistake, the time range was wrong so I was getting the curve decreasing at a higher rate, also I forgot to subtract the mean.